# minimizing parameters in MySQL stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, parameters

I've got a stored procedure that selects IDvars based on 'foo''s value and assigns them variable names that include foo.  I can do this with:

```
CALL db0.genericStoredProc(IDvar, "foo", "'foo'");
```

Ideally, I'd just like to write

```
CALL db0.genericStoredProc(IDvar, "foo");
```

How do I leverage bar, such that I don't need a bar2 parameter?
Here are the relevant parts of my stored procedure.

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS genericStoredProc;
DELIMITER $ $
CREATE PROCEDURE genericStoredProc(myID BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED, bar VARCHAR(5), bar2 VARCHAR(5))
BEGIN
SET @s = CONCAT('SELECT gt.name, gt.junk, gt.junkName, count(gt.idvar) as id_count,
        SUM(CASE 
            WHEN ot.offset <0 THEN 1 
            ELSE 0
        END) AS ', bar,'_id_count
    FROM genericTable gt
        LEFT JOIN otherTable ot ON gt.IDvar2 = ot.IDvar
    WHERE (gt.idvar = ', IDvar, ') AND (ot.prmtr = ', bar2, ')
GROUP BY gt.idvar');

PREPARE stmt FROM @s;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use local variables
like below

```
DELIMITER $ $
CREATE PROCEDURE genericStoredProc(myID BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED, bar VARCHAR(5))
BEGIN
DECLARE bar2 VARCHAR(5);
SET bar2=bar1 ;
```

Comment: I still have some issues.  this implies that my real issue is in getting foo recognized as "foo" in the where clause. Query: CALL genericStoredProc(IDvar, "foo")

Error Code: 1054
Unknown column 'foo' in 'where clause'

Execution Time : 0 sec
Transfer Time  : 0 sec
Total Time     : 3.916 sec

Comment: instead of  (myID BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED, bar VARCHAR(5))  use (IN myID BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED, IN  bar VARCHAR(5))